# Maven upgraded DROOLS version and now can no longer build

Tags: java, maven, drools

I am new to maven and java.  I am working on a Java/DROOLS project.  I was experiencing errors which seemed to be fixed with the next version of DROOLS.  I changed the version in my `pom.xml` and then did mvn package.

The files were downloaded but every line of code that references DROOLS throws a compile error of `package org.drools does not exist`.

```
[ERROR] /C:/Dev/src/main/java/com/company/project/drools/client/DroolsRulesRunner.java:[11,18] package org.drools does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Dev/src/main/java/com/company/project/drools/client/DroolsRulesRunner.java:[12,29] package org.drools.definition does not exist
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**
Here is my pom.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.bericotechnologies</groupId>
  <artifactId>sbt-rules</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <drools.version>7.6.0.Final</drools.version>
    <jbpm5.version>7.6.0.Final</jbpm5.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbpm-flow</artifactId>
      <version>${jbpm5.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbpm-bpmn2</artifactId>
      <version>${jbpm5.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbpm-flow-builder</artifactId>
      <version>${jbpm5.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>pl.maciejwalkowiak</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-drools</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
      <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
      <version>${drools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.core</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
      <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>sqljdbc</artifactId>
      <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.rzo.yajsw</groupId>
      <artifactId>wrapper</artifactId>
      <version>11.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.rzo.yajsw</groupId>
      <artifactId>wrapperApp</artifactId>
      <version>11.11</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jboss</id>
      <name>jboss</name>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>maciejwalkowiak.pl</id>
      <url>https://github.com/maciejwalkowiak/maven-repo/raw/releases/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/rules</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.code.sortpom</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-sortpom-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>sort</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.berico.psip.run.RunDroolsService</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

The only thing that I changed is

```
<properties>
    <drools.version>5.6.0.Final</drools.version>
    <jbpm5.version>5.5.0.Final</jbpm5.version>
  </properties>
```

to

```
<properties>
    <drools.version>7.6.0.Final</drools.version>
    <jbpm5.version>7.6.0.Final</jbpm5.version>
  </properties>
```

If I change it back everything works fine.  I can see the 7.6.0.Final jars in the repository.

Comment: You need to post your full compile error message. Also the title of your question suggests that you changed the version of Maven that you are using not, as I presume you mean, the version of Drools.

Comment: Changed title and included full errors

Comment: Did you do `mvn clean package`? You are probably going to have to post your POM and your code. It's hard to tell exactly what the problem is with few details.

Comment: I have done a clean package.  I have also edited question to include more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have broken imports and you have to fix them.

There's changes in the package structure of Drools between versions `5.6.0.Final` and `7.6.0.Final`. The package "definitions" is now under `org.drools.core.definitions` (`v7.6.0.Final`) and not under `org.drools.definitions` (`5.6.0.Final`).

You need to remove all imports beginning with `org.drools` in your classes and re-import the missing Drools classes again with the new package locations - those from version `7.6.0.Final`.

Comment: I believe we are going to have to go with 7.6 because of corporate policy.  Are there any good developer resources for DROOLS 7.6?  The only books I have found are 5.x and 6.x.  The documentation tends to be abstract and unwieldy.